# Datastax Driver giving connection error after enabling client to node SSL on Cassandra port 9142

Tags: ssl, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Enabled SSL on cassandra nodes on port 9142. The service is running fine when testing it from local but getting AllNodesFailedException when deploying on ECS cluster. Using the same keystore locally. Non SSL Port 9042 is working ok.

> Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]:
> Factory method 'session' threw exception; nested exception is
> com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not
> reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses
> (showing first 3 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more):
> Node(endPoint=ip-10-18-28-203.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.18.28.203:9142,
> hostId=null, hashCode=6551c917):
> [io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out:
> ip-10-18-28-203.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.18.28.203:9142],
> Node(endPoint=ip-10-18-8-110.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.18.8.110:9142,
> hostId=null, hashCode=36985f57):
> [io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out:
> ip-10-18-8-110.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.18.8.110:9142],
> Node(endPoint=ip-10-18-7-47.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.18.7.47:9142,
> hostId=null, hashCode=8eab7e9):
> [io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out:
> ip-10-18-7-47.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.18.7.47:9142]

cassandra.yaml properties

```
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: /etc/cassandra/conf/casskeystore
    keystore_password: changeit
    truststore: conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: cassandra

client_encryption_options:
    enabled: true
    optional: true
    keystore: /etc/cassandra/conf/casskeystore
    keystore_password: changeit
```

Comment: What result do you get if you run `openssl s_client -connect 10.18.28.203:9142` (or to any of the IP addresses)?  Or even `telnet 10.18.28.203 9142`?  Do you get actual TCP connections?  If you can't get OpenSSL to connect, or even just a raw TCP connection that doesn't even try to negotiate SSL, the Cassandra configuration in the cluster probably hasn't been properly configured to run a separate SSL-enabled port.

Comment: Given that is an aws server - did you configure security group rules to permit port 9142?

Comment: @Andrew Thanks man. This is what the issue was, I forgot to enable port 9142 to the security group.